# CakePHP 3 remove WWW-authenticate

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP as a REST API for a single-page app.

Every request gets authenticated and authorized before proceeding.

The problem is, on logging in, if the credentials are wrong, Cake returns 401 and the browser shows its own server log in a popup.

I believe there is a way to stop it by unsetting the `WWW-authenticate header`, but I need to know how. Can someone explain how to unset that header?

Comment: You will need to provide some more info, like your authentication setup code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers are being set in the `\Cake\Auth\BasicAuthenticate` authentication adapter.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php#L85-L110**

It's hardcoded, so if you want to change this behavior, you'll have to create a custom/extended authentication adapter and override this behavior.

Here's a quick example:

**src/Auth/MyCustomBasicAuthenticate.php**

```php
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\BasicAuthenticate;
use Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException;
use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\Network\Response;

class MyCustomBasicAuthenticate extends BasicAuthenticate
{
    public function unauthenticated(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'MyCustomBasic'
    ]
]);
```

See also

- [**Cookbook > Authentication > Creating Custom Authentication Objects**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects)
- [**Cookbook > Authentication > Using Custom Authentication Objects**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-custom-authentication-objects)